# my laptop randomly stops detecting successive key tapping

Tags: keyboard

like, I would tap backspace repeatedly and only one letter is removed and if I wait for a sec it deletes another. rebooting, logging out/in and typing slowly (lol) solves the issue but it's quite annoying and I'm afraid it might not be a software issue at all since this is quite an old (8 year old) used laptop I bought recently :(

I'm using ubuntu (obviously) and I suspect it might be the ssd's fault coz I checked and it apparently showing signs of pre-failure (one sector has died)

Comment: Try booting Windows (of you have it) or from the live Ubuntu installation USB using the Try Ubuntu option. If the problem can be replicated, then it is a hardware problem. Both your SSD and the keyboard may be failing independently.

Comment: I don't have either of those, but think is that it happens randomly for no apparent reason so I'm not exactly sure how I'd replicate it. For example, just after writing that post I logged out/in and the keyboard is working fine :/

Comment: You may also try an external USB keyboard. It may be a loose contact.

Comment: I don't have that immediately either ;-;

Comment: It may be a loose contact. Over time connections tend to come loose.

Comment: it happens for all key all at once and merely logging out/in solves it so I'm pretty sure the issue isn't mechanical

Comment: Is this a Dell laptop, perchance?

Comment: no, it's clevo.

Comment: Do the same problems reoccur when running Ubuntu from a live session with an Ubuntu live USB?